# Flutter: Load JSON data automatically StatefulWidget

Tags: json, flutter, dart, android-asynctask

I'm trying to automatically assign json data to a list without having to press a button, that then calls a method.

For simplicity, here's my method:

```dart
_fetchData() async {
    final response = 
    await http.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos");
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      list = json.decode(response.body) as List;
    } else {
      throw Exception("Failed to load data");
    }
  }
```

I have a StatefulWidget with a variable 'list', and inside the build method, returns a list builder that then uses the data from the list.

How would I do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to call your method in initState. The important bit here is the setState() which triggers a rebuild of the widget.

here's an example:

```
  class _PhotosWidgetState extends State<PhotosWidget> {
    List<dynamic> photos = [];

    @override
    void initState() {
      super.initState();
      setState(() {
        photos = _fetchData();
      });
    }

    List<dynamic> _fetchData() async {
      final response =
          await http.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos");
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        return json.decode(response.body) as List;
      } else {
        throw Exception("Failed to load data");
      }
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return [....your list builder here....];
    }
  }
```

Comment: Since it is async, shouldn't it be `Future<List<dynamic>>`?